# Does TryExecuteTask(task) always block?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I'm writing a FIFO queued thread-limited task scheduler.

Does a call to `TaskScheduler.TryExecuteTask(task)` always block while `task` is executing?  Testing so far indicates that this is the case, however I can't find this documented anywhere.

Is there ever any reason to call `task.Wait()` following the above call?  Doing this results in an `AggregateException` if the task ends in a `Faulted` state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A call to `TryExecuteTask` will always block, it runs the task you are providing it on the scheduler on which you are calling the function and returns if the Task has finished successfully.

If you want the task to run in a different thread: on [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler(v=vs.110).aspx) there is an example on how to use `QueueUserWorkItem` to inform the ThreadPool that there's work to be executed. When you call the `TryExecuteTask` inside there, an available thread will pick it up and executes the task.

`task.Wait()` is generally used when passing the task to a scheduler to block until the task has completed. Since you are not executing your task in a different thread, the code blocks anyway and calling `task.Wait()` would be redundant.

Comment: Minor issue for readability:  In first sentence above, was the word "scheduler" supposed to be "thread" in this phrase:  " it runs the task you are providing it on the [~~scheduler~~ thread] on which you are calling the function"?